# C++ conversion from decimal degrees to DMS

Tags: c++, precision, degrees

I have the following code to convert decimal degrees to/from degrees,minutes,seconds.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

void toDMS(double decimalDegrees, int& degrees, unsigned int& minutes, double& seconds)
{
    degrees = static_cast<int>(decimalDegrees);
    double remainingMinutes = fabs(decimalDegrees - degrees) * 60.0;
    minutes = static_cast<unsigned int>(remainingMinutes);
    seconds = (remainingMinutes - minutes) * 60.0;
}
double toDecimalDegrees(int degrees, unsigned int minutes, double seconds)
{
    if (degrees >= 0.0)
        return fabs(degrees) + (minutes / 60.0) + (seconds / 3600.0);
    else
        return -(fabs(degrees) + (minutes / 60.0) + (seconds / 3600.0));
}
```

But when I run the following test :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double decimalDegrees = 45.666666666666664;
    int degrees; unsigned int minutes; double seconds;
    toDMS(decimalDegrees, degrees, minutes, seconds);
    std::cout << "DMS = " << degrees << ", " << minutes << ", " << seconds << std::endl;
}
```

I get : `45, 39, 60`

Instead of : `45, 40, 0`

This is due to a precision issue, `remainingMinutes` contains `39.9999999...` instead of `40.0`.

I can get around with something like :

```
    double remainingMinutes = fabs(decimalDegrees - degrees) * 60.0;
    double ceil = std::ceil(remainingMinutes);
    if (ceil - remainingMinutes <= 1.0e-10)
        remainingMinutes = ceil;
```

But I don't like this, because I must use an arbitrary precision and the bug could happen with other numerical values.

Anyone has a better alternative ?
Many thanks !

Comment: What does your question have to do with `dms` (Document Management System)?

Comment: So use a type that allows for arbitrary precision.

Comment: `double decimalDegrees = 45.666666666666664;` -- What is the actual precision your application will be using?  If it's two or three decimal places, then the calculations could be done in integer.

Comment: You are always going to have inaccuracies with floating point.  Typically you can add 1 before the division to get it to truncate correctly.

Comment: You could do something like `if (seconds >= 60) { seconds -= 60; ++minutes; }` (and probably a similar adjustment for minutes to degrees) to ensure you end up with sane numbers. Though come to think of it, in your example you are probably ending up with `{45, 39, 59.99999...}`, which is arguably a correct answer. It's just that `59.99999...` gets printed as `60` when you don't specify a high enough precision.

Comment: Why don't you have a dedicated datatype for a DMS representation of an angle? Also, make sure you have unit tests for conversions, especially the corner (no pun ;) ) cases. Further, this conversion won't be lossless, so you can't expect a perfect roundtrip.

Comment: BTW: The error in your code is that you round each segment of your DMS representation separately. If you want to convert it to a string, you need to round the seconds part. But, if that causes an overflow, you must incorporate that into the minutes and possibly the degrees. If you can, use radians for angles, not degrees, not DMS. When you display an angle or receive input, you can convert there and then.

Comment: The problem is you specify dec sec, but expect int sec. Take dec deg * 3600 to get total dec sec.  At this point you have to decide if you want dec sec or int sec.  If you want dec sec then you'll get same as you have 45, 39, 59.999..., if you want int sec then round at that point, then use mod 60 to get sec, then get int min, then get int deg.

Comment: Why are you truncating the `decimalDegrees` to an integer?  You can have a loss of precision.  I recommend keeping DM&S as floating point and after the calcluation go ahead and round or truncate the DM&S variables to integers.